# Why is my object look so weird in rendered mode?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a table with a simple UV added as a material. 
Here is my table in material view:
    [image: Material Image]
Below is my table in Rendered:
[image: Rendered Image]

Any idea what I can do to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is called z-fighting. That means, that you have overlapping geometry. Most likely, you have objects in your scene, that are invisible for viewport rendering (the eye icon in the outliner), but visible for rendered view (the camera icon).